# Memory issues drawing 5 small images

Tags: android

My app is using way too much memory, and I'm not too sure why. I'm making a solitaire game. I'm using a chained ConstraintLayout of 10 equal width RelativeLayouts (1 for each stack of cards). [I know I can use other Viewgroups].

My app is using ~15mb memory, until I do this;

```
public void DrawCardsMat0()
{
    RelativeLayout mat = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.PLAY_Mat0);
    mat.removeAllViews();
    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);

    for (PlayingCard playingCard : Stack0.Cards)
    {
        ImageView myImg = GetCardImage(playingCard);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(CardWidth, CardHeight);
        lay.setMargins(0, playingCard.UI_MarginTop, 0, 0);
        mat.addView(myImg, lay);
    }
}
```

and

```
public ImageView GetCardImage(PlayingCard playingCard)
{
    ImageView myImg = new ImageView(this);
    // a simple switch is used to here to pick the drawable. Removed as there's 52 cards)
    myImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.s1); 
    return myImg;
}
```

CardWidth and CardHeight are ints (150 and 210, roughly. Pixels).

This draws FIVE cards, and each .jpg is ~60KB (yes, KB). This results in 60MB of memory usage. 10 cols == 600mb of memory (I assume, as it's OOM before then).

The images are in a RelativeLayout, and are placed on top of each other. MarginTop is used to "stack" them.

thanks in advance

--- update 1 ---

I'm now using a 46KB bmp image. 
Creating 5 ImageViews (one stack's worth) in XML (and don't call anything in code) uses ~50mb memory. Tested using a LinearLayout. 
Creating same images in-code uses same amount of memory.

--- update 2 ---
If I create a new Activity, with just a simple LinearLayout and 5 ImageViews, and no java code, it still uses ~50MB memory.

Comment: .jpg is compression, which exist only in file, in runtime memory each image is in uncompressed format. To get rough estimation about the card size in memory, you can just try to save it as .bmp

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Saved 1 image as bmp, it's roughly ~1mb.

Comment: I've resized (smaller) a single image, and saved it as a bmp. It's 124KB. Then used that image for all 5 cards. Memory has dropped from ~60MB to ~40MB.

Comment: relativeLayout cost a lot try using frameLayout

Comment: @JCDecary `RelativeLayout` is costly only in terms of layout/measure time (and you feel it only in case of complex layout), nothing scary considering memory consumption.

Answer (score 1):

When working with bitmaps, you should always be careful. I'll describe the most important points and considering them, you can change the way work with card images is organized.

1. Bitmap in memory always exists in uncompressed format, so its size will be different from the size of your `.jpg`/`.png`/`.webp`/`.[whatever compressed format]`. The actual size depends on the [Bitmap.Config](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html), but by default Android will use `ARGB_8888` (1 byte for alpha channel, 1 byte for each of R/G/B channels). You can roughly estimate the size in memory by saving the image in `.bmp` format.
2. When you use `<bitmap>` tag with drawable, it means in runtime bitmap will be wrapped in [BitmapDrawable](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.java). As you can see, by default bitmap will be loaded as-is, taking original size.
3. When you call `myImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.s1)` it means that **bitmap will have the same size as before in memory**, it will be just scaled by using the matrix depending on the size of `ImageView` and `scaleType` you specified.
4. Considering that, probably you may want to load downscaled bitmap to the memory, depending on the view size. You can do that by using `BitmapFactory` class instead. I suggest you to read these 2 articles in order to understand how Android is working with bitmaps: [Managing Bitmap Memory](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/manage-memory.html) and [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html).
5. You may also consider using some image library, like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) which can load downscaled bitmap depending on the size of `ImageView`. You can also try to use [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/) which keeps bitmap outside of `JVM` heap.
6. If you have such possibility, better to have cards in `SVG` format. Then you can work with vectors instead of having bitmap, which is much more memory-friendly (because `SVG` is just a set of instructions on how to draw). However in case of really complex `SVG` file you can hit another problem - it will take a lot of time to draw it. Check [this](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.v84hg9oxw) article on how to use it with `ImageView`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll digest and read, then get back to you. Thanks again!